# How to create facebook feed style cards in UITableView with Rubymotion?

Tags: ios, uitableview, rubymotion

I've been trying to recreate the facebook style feed using a UITableView without much success. My first idea was to add a new view to the cell that contained the 'card' but I have not been able to make this work. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I go about doing this?

My other concern is how do I make each cell vary in height dependant on content?

Attached is an image of the facebook UI to hopefully explain what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Facebook Feed UI]

Comment: This is a pretty vague question. You'll get better answers if you provide code examples of what you've tried.

Comment: Any details available on how you finally did this?  I have the same issues in terms of a table with "cards" and another table for messages (comments).  Would be interested in how you did it in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would subclass UITableViewCell, extend initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: with custom initialization code, and override layoutSubviews to position everything based on your variable content.

Based on a label's content and its UIFont, you can calculate its width and height.

```
'Wow! Nice Photo!'.sizeWithFont(UIFont.fontWithName('Helvetica', size: 18.0))
 # CGSize width=144.0 height=22.0>
```

Here's a template for how I would setup a variable UITableViewCell subclass:

```
class AwesomeCell < UITableViewCell
  def initWithStyle(style, reuseIdentifier: reuse_identifier)
    super.tap do |cell|
      # initialize and add your subviews to contentView
    end
  end

  def layoutSubview
    # layout your subviews
  end

  def calculated_height
    # calculate your height
  end      
end
```

But as aceofspades pointed out, you should be aware of the performance impact of dynamically determining the height of UITableViewCells.

If you can get away with showing a fixed number of lines within the label to keep the cell's overall height fixed, you'd get much better performance.

Even creating a few different fixed height UITableViewCell subclasses and using the appropriate one based on the incoming content would probably yield a more performant UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add subviews to the `contentView` of your `UITableViewCell` instances. To control row height, use `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` however check the docs for notes about performance impact of this.